# EJB automatic timers, locking, timeouts and long-running methods

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.0

I have few questions regarding safety and correctness of following hypothetical timer service:

```
@Singleton
public class MyTimerService {

  @Schedule(second = "*", minute = "*", hour = "*", persistent = false)
  public void checkTakingOneMinute() {
    // code below takes a minute or so
  }
}
```

All I want to do here, is to check something as soon as possible (every second in this case). As I understand it, method `checkTakingOneMinute()` wont start new check until it finishes previous call. That's what I want, but I'm worrying about container's internals: will method execution be just skipped when busy or it will be locked and put into a sort of queue with subsequent lock timeouts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The EJB specification requires that the container schedule "catch up" timer events if it's unable to fire a timer because it was already running.  In practice, containers probably recalculate the next fire time after the method has completed, and then immediately re-execute if the next fire time is "before" the current time.  I know this is how WebSphere Application Server works.

Note that the default `ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagemementType.CONTAINER)` for the bean and `Lock(LockType.WRITE)` for the timer method will prevent any other methods from being executed.  If you need other methods on that bean, you might consider using `ConcurrencyManagementType.BEAN`.

Comment: Looks like my question is almost the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691835/timer-service-in-ejb-3-1-schedule-calling-timeout-problem , code rewritten, your solution works great, thanks.

Comment: You're probably right.  I tend to write personalized/customized answers rather than search for dups (even ones that I answered and forgot about!).

Answer (score 3):

We use Timers in our app but inside of Weblogic. As far as I know, if the timer thread is busy processing something while it is woken up for the next schedule, the woken up process will wait for the next schedule to re-execute but this could be controlled based on some parameters. I found some documentation on how it is done in Websphere below (I am not sure what those configurable parameters are for Websphere) - may this link will help in clarifying your doubts. There they have mentioned about missed timers (Retries and missed timeouts section), which is what you are concerned about.

[EJB timers in Websphere](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/tejb_timerserviceejb_enh.html)

Comment: good article, thanks. You might be also interested in @bkail solution, see my comment under his answer.